# How the check that theano is only using FP32?

Tags: neural-network, theano, keras, theano-cuda

In my .theanorc file I have set the parameter...

```
[global]
floatX = float32
```

However when I run keras with the theano backend and make calls to model.predict the numpy datatype of the returned array is always of type FP64 not FP32.  I am not sure if this is a problem or if keras / theano makes a conversion to FP32 before executing on the GPU.  Is there a way to check. I would like it if theano could post and error or warning if I try to use FP64 on the GPU.

Answer (score 3):

To check the type of `floatX` you can simply run

```
import theano
print theano.config.floatX
```

If that code prints `'float32'` then theano will print out a warning when you try to use `float64` as input for gpu computations. This can be suppressed though if you add the keyword argument [`allow_downcast`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/function.html#function.In.allow_downcast), so make sure that you don't have this keyword in `theano.function` when you are compiling the graph.